# Do I need a StatefulWidget if my app is using bloc?

Tags: dart, flutter, reactivex

I'm missing something.

I recently watched the talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI&feature=youtu.be), where the flutter devs are going through using the bloc development method with reactivex in Dart. If I'm using these streams and streamBuilders to manage data flowing through my app, and rebuild appropriately, does it behoove me to use a StatefulWidget, where I'm using the bloc method anyway? I guess more specifically, why would I want to complicate my app using streams and states, when I could just use streams, wrap what I need to in a provider, wrap some widgets in a streamBuilder, and call it a day?

Answer (score 13):

When using `StreamBuilder` you are in fact using a `StatefulWidget` which listen to that `Stream`. The only difference is that you don't write `setState` yourself.

Another common use-case is for animations. If you want transitions such as fade/translate/whatever; you'll have to use `AnimationController`. Which you will store inside a custom `StatefulWidget`

Comment: Also for text input fields (`TextInputController`)

Answer (score 12):

> does it behoove me to use a StatefulWidget, where I'm using the bloc method anyway? I guess more specifically, why would I want to complicate my app using streams and states, when I could just use streams, wrap what I need to in a provider, wrap some widgets in a streamBuilder, and call it a day?

The answer to your questions depends on what your goals are.

A **StatefulWidget** does not scale to larger applications. The BLOC pattern does.

Why is **StatefulWidget** not good for larger applications?

Communicating information from one screen to a sibling screen tends to be challenging, meaning you have to write a lot of code to transfer data from one screen to another. It is possible, but it tends to be a pain and that's what the BLOC pattern solves.

It makes it easy to share information between multiple widgets inside our application.

**BLOC** stands for **B**usiness **LO**gic **C**omponent and its idea is to house all the data or state inside the application inside one area. It's outside the rest of the application and makes it easy to access.

That's different from a **StatefulWidget**, because with a BLOC all the data can live within one class outside the component hierarchy. So the state is being centralized to some outside object.

So with the BLOC pattern you do need a solid understanding of streams and you mentioned the **StreamBuilder** Widget which is were flutter and streams really come together.

The **StreamBuilder** takes a stream and a builder function and anytime that StreamBuilder sees a new piece of data it will call the builder function and re render itself on our mobile device, so it would look something like this:

```
Widget emailField() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.email,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'you@example.com',
              labelText: 'Email Address',
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

The above approach being a single global instance which works fine for small application.

The provider you mentioned is a class that extends the inherited widget base class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'bloc.dart';

class Provider extends InheritedWidget {
  final bloc = Bloc();

  bool updateShouldNotify(_) => true;

  static Bloc of(BuildContext, context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(Provider) as Provider).bloc;
  }
}
```

Comment: `A StatefulWidget does not scale to larger applications. The BLOC pattern does`

What utter opinionated nonsense. Not that I disagree with BLoC pattern, but the statement that "StatefulWidget" won't scale is silly and wrong.

Comment: @Adam please prove it instead of an nonsense comment.

Comment: @LạngHoàng scroll down (not my answer) https://stackoverflow.com/a/69698751/954940

Comment: now my question is do we have to totally eliminate stateful widgets? for example even for holding a textfield state should we use bloc? or we can go with stateful widget for these minor things.

Answer (score 7):

Let me share my insights after working many years with Flutter, Bloc and `StatefulWidget`s approaches.

Whenever you find yourself in a situation that you want to make two `StatefulWidget` communicate, then think twice if Bloc is an answer.

I have gone too far with **bloc-everything** approach as was suggested in their docs
and expected that `bloc` would help me achieve better modularity in code. I used `BlocListener`s to utilize `listener:` argument and call `setState()` in it... Then I tried with `BlocBuilder`s. I have always reached the dead end and got many bugs while integrating `StatefulWidget` closely with `Bloc`. Why, you ask? Just to achieve this cleany, shiny modularity to have widgets in separate files and make them reusable and all that clean-code jazz.

However, that's not the case for `StatefulWidget` when it comes to practice.

Let me give you my mental model while approaching designing the widget. As for the example I will work on the following UI component - the vertical `Column` that contains two `ListItem`s that every one composes of two `Switch`es, where the top switch toggles the bottom one. When a parent preference switch is toggled off, then it also disables the child one.

Sample UI:

[image: The UI]

Video with such requirement to be fulfilled:

[image: desired case]

How to code such UI?
The first idea is to create:

- `ParentPreferenceWidget.dart`
- `ChildPreferenceWidget.dart`
- `TitleSectionWidget.dart`

Column would look like:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    ParentPreferenceWidget(...),
    ChildPreferenceWidget(...),
    TitleSectionWidget(...),
    ParentPreferenceWidget(...),
    ChildPreferenceWidget(...),
    TitleSectionWidget(...),
  ]
)
```

Ok, so the UI was coded. And how to make those `Swtich`es communicate? (`ParentPreferenceWidget` with `ChildPreferenceWidget` one).

Well, the problem arises, as `ParentPreferenceWidget` and `ChildPreferenceWidget` will have a have `Switch` widget.

A `Switch` widget needs a `value:` parameter and is capable of running animation.

In every tutorial it is required to call `setState` for such Widget which aggregates `Switch`. So such widgets need to extend `StatefulWidget`.

A note for `StatefulWidget`s - their associated `State` objects have longer lifecylce than `StatelessWidgets`. And it made because of
performance reasons. [Resource here](https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/stateful-widget-lifecycle).

So `State` objects are not destroyed during a widget tree rebuild phase, while `StatelessWidgets` are destroyed and recreated. This enables running the animation smoothly for the first case.

So how to use `bloc` then?

This could come to your mind (pseudo-code):

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    BlocProvider<...>(
      create: ...
      child: Column(
        children: [
           ParentPreferenceWidget(...), // will fire bloc events
           BlocBuilder<...>(
             builder: (context, state) => ChildPreferenceWidget(state, ...) // this will rebuild
           )  
        ]
      )
    ),
    TitleSectionWidget(...),
    BlocProvider<...>(
      create: ...
      child: Column(
        children: [
           ParentPreferenceWidget(...), // will fire bloc events
           BlocBuilder<...>(
             builder: (context, state) => ChildPreferenceWidget(state, ...) // this will rebuild
           )  
        ]
      )
    ),
    TitleSectionWidget(...),
  ]
)
```

Beware! Whenever event is fired, a new instance of `PreferenceWidget` is created. We've just said before that this is a `StatefulWidget`, hence no performance gain at all.

And also there will be `bloc` events multiplication (either you create separate bloc or reuse one). Either the new states are added and code complexity will grow.

And what if you want to **move bloc higher**? Like it would become a master one, so two `ParentPreferenceWidget` can communicate.

Then what you need to do, is to add more data to bloc events like `bool wasFiredFromBlocA`. This becomes a **bloc hell**.

Unfortunately, the only reasonable solution I came up with was to return to the basics and write the whole `ParentPreferenceWidget` and `ChildPreferenceWidget` functionality inside a single `Stateful` widget.

This is motivated by the problems mentioned about while using single  or multiple `Bloc`s and making them communicate the state to child widgets.

So for my newly created Parent-Child widget, a `State` object contains two fields, like this:

```dart
bool _switchParentState;
bool _switchChildState;
```

And voila - this way state objects live as long as expected and handle the state correctly.

As for the `bloc` - you can manage such internal state with the help of `BlocListener` if you really want to listen to some parent bloc from the 'outside'.

This could look like this:

```dart
return BlocListener(
  listener: (context, state) {
    setState(() {
        // use state to set state
    });
  },
  child: ... // build the widget tree normally.
)
```

A note - just remember to use `ValueKey` or some other `Key` for any `StatefulWidget` that is duplicated inside the view hierarchy. As they need to be differentiated by the Flutter framework in case of `State` objects.

And that's how I perceive this after struggling a lot. The `bloc` is a great solution for simple cases. But when it comes to framework principles and some complex state mutations, it is better to stick to the basics.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. I will consider this idea :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `StatelessWidget` or a `StatefulWidget` and everything will work fine but, in those instances where I have needed to initialise state in my bloc, I have used a `StatefulWidget` and put my initialisation logic inside the `initState()` override.

*(please correct me kindly if this isn't best practice, I'm new to bloc, flutter and streams!)*

Comment: Now that you've got some experience (I assume), would you still do that ?

Answer (score 2):

BLoC or another state management solution is okay if you want to handle more complex state across classes in your app. However, that does not mean you don't need stateful widgets anymore. This is really a big misunderstanding of stateless and stateful widgets.

Say, if you want to create a custom widget which resizes itself on certain gestures, or you want it to change color or you want it to rebuild itself according to different properties (could be just a boolean value for a on/off switch), would you create a bloc for that? Not at all.

The state remains in your same widget and only some properties are changing inside of it. For doing that I highly recommend you just use a stateful widget. It has nothing to do with state management packages or similar.